# Starting a tkinter Progressbar before a ttk Treeview window opens

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am working on a python program wherein a button calls a function using command that then (i) walks two directories replete with many subdirectories, files, etc., (ii) compares what is in each directory, and (iii) opens up a ttk treeview window and populates that treeview window with the results of the comparison. Depending on the size of the directories this can take some time. And I would like to let the user know the program is working (it sometimes takes so long Windows gives a program not-responding message, but it is in fact working). I would like to start a progress bar when the button that calls the function is pressed. But nothing starts, or displays, or opens, unless and until the treeview window opens and populates. So after some time, the user will see the treeview, and simultaneously the empty status bar or other label I tried to create to tell the use to hang tight. Obviously this defeats the purpose. This happens even if I create a discrete function which calls a second function. I do not want to interrupt the execution and require the use to hit a button or the like to continue. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: probably your function is blocking `GUI`/`Tkinter` and `mainloop` can't run and it can't update widget. You will have to run your function in separated thread. OR between lines you will have to run `root.update()` and this will allow `mainloop` to update window.

Comment: Thank you! The update method allowed me to create a toplevel window with a label that tells the user things are in progress.